# Laravel 5 make seed to database not working

Tags: php, laravel

I try to seed a user to the database but cannot. I could easely create the migration tables, so the problem is not in the connection to the database, but I cannot create a user, I get the "Class UsersTableSeeder does not exist" error. How can I solve it? (I use laravel 5.3)

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONmzU.jpg)

Here is my code:

DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{

      public function run()
      {
          $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
      }
}
```

UsersTableSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use App/User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
public function run()
{
    \DB::table('users')->delete();
    User::create([
      'name' => 'lamin',
      'email' => 'lamin@laravel.com',
      'password' => bcrypt('lamin')
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run `composer dumpauto` command and then run seeder again.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project